# ”ALVRES.RES を開けません”というエラー

Tags: c++

現在、embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。
エラーが発生したのですが、

> （エラー内容）
>   [ilink32 エラー] Error: ファイル 'ALVRES.RES' を開けません
>   [ilink32 エラー] Error: ファイル 'ADVMEMO.RES' を開けません
>   [ilink32 エラー] Error: ファイル 'ADVFINDDIALOGFORM.DFM' を開けません
>   [ilink32 エラー] Error: ファイル 'ADVREPLACEDIALOGFORM.DFM' を開けません
>   [ilink32 エラー] Error: リンクを実行できません

このようなエラーがでてきたのですが、”ALVRES.RES”という名前をプロジェクト内のファイルやコード内でテキスト検索しても全く出てきません。

解決方法や、このRESファイルというのはどういう意味なのかもご教示よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: この商業ソフト[TMS Component Pack（英語版）](https://www.componentsource.co.jp/product/tms-component-pack-j/prices)の一部らしいですね。使われているのは古い版でしょうけれど。販売元に聞いてみたらどうでしょうか。開発元の最新はこちらの様です。[TMS VCL UI Pack](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsvcluipack.asp)

Comment: 現在、TMS VCL UI Packのトライアル版をインストールして使用しています。何か製品版と違い制限があるかどうかなどメーカーに問い合わせてみたいと思います。